# asp.net: textboxes disappear after i publish application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

When i compile my web app and run it in the browser, it looks good and the textboxes appear; however, after i publish it, the textboxes are not visible anymore. i believe it is a CSS error because the textboxes still exist. i am able to type in them; however it does not show the white background of the textbox, it simply blends into the background. what am i doing wrong? here's my code:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href="../niceforms/niceforms-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../niceforms/niceforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--The below is to make the calendar look nice!-->
    <link href="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .list-problems {
        height:600px !important;
        width:400px !important;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    </style>



    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
        //$("#occurrence_dateTextBox").mask("99/99/9999");
        //$("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#<%= occurrence_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        $("#<%= report_dateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        //$(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

    });



    function getselectedproblems() {
        ob = document.getElementById('lstProblems');
        var problemlist = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
            if (ob.options[i].selected) {
                //alert(ob.options[i].value);
                problemlist = problemlist + ';' + ob.options[i].value; //Do something useful here
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("HiddenProblemList").value=problemlist;
    }

    </script>



</head>
<body><div id="container">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="niceform">

        <fieldset>

        <legend>Section A</legend>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="occurrence_dateTextBox" >Occurrence Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_dateTextBox">Report Date:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="report_dateTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>


        <dl>

            <dt><label for="spec_idTextBox">Specimen ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="spec_idTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="batch_idTextBox">Batch ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="batch_idTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="report_byTextBox">Report By:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="report_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="identified_byTextBox">Identified ID:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="identified_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>
        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section B</legend>



        <dl>
            <dt><label for="lstProblems">Problems List:</label></dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstProblems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                    CssClass="list-problems" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Column1" 
                    DataValueField="Column1"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LOM %>" 
                    SelectCommand="select '[' + category + ']' + ' ' + description from tblProblemList">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </dd>

        </dl>  





        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section C</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox">Issue/Error Identified By:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_c_commentsTextBox">Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_commentsTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>       

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section D</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_d_investigationTextBox">Investigation:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_d_investigationTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section E</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox">Corrective Action:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox" runat="server" height="200" TextMode="MultiLine" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>


        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Section F</legend>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="section_f_commentsTextBox">Comments:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="section_f_commentsTextBox" runat="server" size="50"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Pre-Analytical</legend>


        <dl>
            <dt><label for="CheckBox1">PreAnalytical?</label></dt>
            <dd> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                            Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>

            <dt><label for="prePracticeCodeTextBox">Practice Code:</label></dt>
            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="prePracticeCodeTextBox" runat="server" Visible="false"/></dd>


        </dl>

        <dl>

            <dt><label for="preContactTextBox1">Contact:</label></dt>

            <dd><asp:TextBox ID="preContactTextBox" runat="server" Visible="false"/></dd>


        </dl>

        </fieldset>


        <input id="HiddenProblemList" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData"  OnClientClick="getselectedproblems()"/>


    </form>


</div></body>
</html>
```

here is how i published my application:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/75458540.png/

here is the CSS file:

```
/*Defaults Styling*/
body {font:12px/17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; background:#ccc; padding:40px 20px 20px 20px;}
fieldset {background:#f2f2e6; padding:10px; border:1px solid #fff; border-color:#fff #666661 #666661 #fff; margin-bottom:36px; width:600px;}
input, textarea, select {font:12px/12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:0;}
fieldset.action {background:#9da2a6; border-color:#e5e5e5 #797c80 #797c80 #e5e5e5; margin-top:-20px;}
legend {background:#bfbf30; color:#fff; font:17px/21px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:0 10px; margin:-26px 0 0 -11px; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #fff; border-color:#e5e5c3 #505014 #505014 #e5e5c3;}
label {font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#666;}
label.opt {font-weight:normal;}
dl {clear:both;}
dt {float:left; text-align:right; width:90px; line-height:25px; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}
dd {float:left; width:475px; line-height:25px; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
#footer {font-size:11px;}

#container {width:700px; margin:0 auto;}

/*##########################################
Script: Niceforms 2.0
Theme: StandardBlue
Author: Lucian Slatineanu
URL: http://www.emblematiq.com/
##########################################*/

/*Text inputs*/
.NFText {border:none; vertical-align:middle; font:12px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:none;}
.NFTextCenter {height:15px; background:url(img/input.png) repeat-x 0 0; padding:3px 0; margin:0; float:left; line-height:15px;}
.NFTextLeft, .NFTextRight {width:7px; height:21px; vertical-align:middle; float:left;}
.NFTextLeft {background:url(img/input-left.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFTextRight {background:url(img/input-right.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
/*Radio*/
.NFRadio {cursor:pointer; position:absolute; display:block; width:13px; height:13px; border:1px solid transparent; background:url(img/radio.png) no-repeat 0 0; z-index:2;}
/*Checkbox*/
.NFCheck {cursor:pointer; position:absolute; width:12px; height:12px; border:1px solid transparent; background:url(img/checkbox.png) no-repeat 0 0; z-index:2;}
/*Buttons*/
.NFButton {width:auto; height:26px; color:#fff; padding:0 2px; background:url(img/button.png) repeat-x 0 0; cursor:pointer; border:none; font:10px/26px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:1px; vertical-align:middle;}
.NFButtonLeft, .NFButtonRight {width:6px; height:26px; vertical-align:middle;}
.NFButtonLeft {background:url(img/button-left.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFButtonRight {background:url(img/button-right.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
/*Textareas*/
.NFTextarea {border:none; background:none; font:12px/12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0;}
.NFTextareaTop, .NFTextareaBottom {height:5px; clear:both; float:none; padding-right:10px;}
.NFTextareaTop {background:url(img/textarea-tr.png) no-repeat 100% 0;}
.NFTextareaBottom {background:url(img/textarea-br.png) no-repeat 100% 0; margin-bottom:5px;}
.NFTextareaTopLeft, .NFTextareaBottomLeft {width:5px; height:5px;}
.NFTextareaTopLeft {background:#f2f2e6 url(img/textarea-tl.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFTextareaBottomLeft {background:#f2f2e6 url(img/textarea-bl.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFTextareaLeft, .NFTextareaRight, .NFTextareaLeftH, .NFTextareaRightH {float:left; padding-bottom:5px;}
.NFTextareaLeft, .NFTextareaLeftH {width:5px;}
.NFTextareaLeft {background:url(img/textarea-l-off.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
.NFTextareaLeftH {background:url(img/textarea-l-over.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
.NFTextareaRight, .NFTextareaRightH {padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:0;}
.NFTextareaRight {background:url(img/textarea-r-off.png) repeat-y 100% 0;}
.NFTextareaRightH {background:url(img/textarea-r-over.png) repeat-y 100% 100%;}
/*Files*/
.NFFileButton {padding-bottom:0; vertical-align:bottom; cursor:pointer; background:url(img/file.png) no-repeat 0 0; width:60px; height:21px;}
.NFFile {position:relative; margin-bottom:5px;}
.NFFile input.NFhidden {position:relative; filter:alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0; z-index:2; cursor:pointer; text-align:left;}
.NFFileNew {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1;}
/*Selects*/
.NFSelect {height:21px; position:absolute; border:1px solid transparent;}
.NFSelectLeft {float:left; width:3px; height:21px; background:url(img/select-left.png) no-repeat 0 0; vertical-align:middle;}
.NFSelectRight {height:21px; width:auto; background:url(img/select-right.png) no-repeat 100% 0; cursor:pointer; font:12px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; padding-left:3px; margin-left:3px;}
.NFSelectTarget {position:absolute; background:none; margin-left:-13px; margin-top:18px; z-index:3; left:0; top:0; padding-bottom:13px;}
.NFSelectOptions {position:relative; background:#707175; margin-left:16px; margin-top:0; list-style:none; padding:4px 0; color:#fff; font:11px/13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; z-index:4; max-height:200px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; left:0; top:0;}
.NFSelectOptions li {padding-bottom:1px;}
.NFSelectOptions a {display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#fff; padding:2px 3px; background:none;}
.NFSelectOptions a.NFOptionActive {background:#464646;}
.NFSelectOptions a:hover {background:#333;}
/*Multiple Selects*/
.NFMultiSelect {border:0; background:none; margin:0;}
.NFMultiSelectTop, .NFMultiSelectBottom {height:5px; clear:both; float:none; padding-right:10px;}
.NFMultiSelectTop {background:url(img/textarea-tr.png) no-repeat 100% 0;}
.NFMultiSelectBottom {background:url(img/textarea-br.png) no-repeat 100% 0; margin-bottom:5px;}
.NFMultiSelectTopLeft, .NFMultiSelectBottomLeft {width:5px; height:5px;}
.NFMultiSelectTopLeft {background:#f2f2e6 url(img/textarea-tl.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFMultiSelectBottomLeft {background:#f2f2e6 url(img/textarea-bl.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
.NFMultiSelectLeft, .NFMultiSelectRight, .NFMultiSelectLeftH, .NFMultiSelectRightH {float:left; padding-bottom:5px;}
.NFMultiSelectLeft, .NFMultiSelectLeftH {width:5px;}
.NFMultiSelectLeft {background:url(img/textarea-l-off.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
.NFMultiSelectLeftH {background:url(img/textarea-l-over.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
.NFMultiSelectRight, .NFMultiSelectRightH {padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:0;}
.NFMultiSelectRight {background:url(img/textarea-r-off.png) repeat-y 100% 0;}
.NFMultiSelectRightH {background:url(img/textarea-r-over.png) repeat-y 100% 0;}

/*Focused*/
.NFfocused {border:1px dotted #666;}
/*Hovered*/
.NFh {background-position:0 100%;}
.NFhr {background-position:100% 100%;}
/*Hidden*/
.NFhidden {opacity:0; z-index:-1; position:relative;}
/*Safari*/
select, input, textarea, button {outline:none; resize:none;}
```

Comment: how did you deploy / publish your web application? has anything changed?

Comment: @david this is how i did it http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/75458540.png/ and i did not change anything at all

Comment: @davide im not sure if it is associated with the publishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. First if you think it is CSS just remove the CSS file and test it.
2. You are referencing external CSS file, please attach CSS so we can see or at least the portion for textbox CSS if you are using that.

### Update

I am using VS 2008 here and I ran the above code with CSS and this is what I am coming up with.

[image]

Comment: I am checking and not finding any problem with CSS which pertain to textbox,dl,dt,dd,fieldset. In fact when I make a page with fieldset, dl wrapper with dt around label and dd around textbox it works just fine and body doesn't have any error as well.